# Where can I find the Pillars of Strength

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've got a quest to find the Pillars of Strength for the Batarians.  It says to go to Kite's Nest, but I'm unsure of where to look once I get there.  I keep getting chased away by Reapers before I can find the artifact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pillar's of Stregth is available on Planet Khar’shan in Harsha galazy of the Kite's Nest system. Once you're close to the planet, just scan it, you'll notice that EDI will anounce that point of interest has been detected. Just enter the orbit & scan the planet to find it.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't that be Hersa system in the Kite's Nest cluster in the Milky Way galaxy?